# Why is the reducer seemingly called by default in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am running a simple Redux reducer and store, but for some reason the reducer is called by default. Is that normal?

```
const apiWrapper = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "HELLO":
      console.log("hello");
      return state;
      break;
    default:
      console.log("default");
  }
}

const { createStore } = Redux;

const store = createStore(apiWrapper);

store.dispatch({ type: "HELLO" });
```

The snippet above outputs:

```
"default"
"hello"
```

I am only expecting it to log `hello`, why is `default` there too? Here's a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xiliyazile/edit?js,console).

Comment: You could just log `action`...

Comment: Get the Chrome `Redux` plugin and you can actually walk through the state and see all actions that trigger and the state at each step.

Comment: great suggestion, thanks man @samanime

Comment: but the console log would be "undefined" not "default", since I didn't call it with an action @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: It wouldn't (shouldn't) be undefined.

Comment: You mean it would be `INIT` for the initial call @OliverCharlesworth?  But what if I just wanted to print "default" and not "INIT" and all the internals of redux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redux internally dispatches a dummy action when creating the store in order to set up the initial state. Per the [Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html):

> When a store is created, Redux dispatches a dummy action to your reducer to populate the store with the initial state. You are not meant to handle the dummy action directly. Just remember that your reducer should return some kind of initial state if the state given to it as the first argument is undefined, and you're all set.

So when your reducer *is first called*, `state` will be undefined thus your default value `{}` will be used. Also, it will go to the `default` case because you're not supposed to explicitly handle the action, and thus you get the `console.log`. Make sure to return the state in the `default` case to set up initial state correctly.

---

Just out of curiosity, the action type the first dummy call Redux does is `"@@redux/INIT"` signifying that Redux is initializing the store and testing it. A similar thing happens with `combineReducers` to test for bad patterns in reducers. Specifically, in [the source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L245):

> ```
> // When a store is created, an "INIT" action is dispatched so that every
> // reducer returns their initial state. This effectively populates
> // the initial state tree.
> dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.INIT })
> ```

So the initial dispatch essentially gives each reducer its respective slice of state, and populates the initial state tree.

Comment: Holly molly! I think you just gave me the mental "click" I needed to fully understand redux and initial state!

Comment: @user123 No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Yep, excellent answer from @Andrew Li.  You may also want to read through the [Structuring Reducers - Initializing State](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html) section of the docs, which explains the interaction between the `preloadedState` argument to `createStore()`, default values for reducers, and the `combineReducers()` utility function.